# Load different roles based on selection

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-authorization

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application where users can be assigned different roles for different asset types. They are able to view assets that belong to different groups (asset type), one at a time.

Depending on the asset type of the asset that is being viewed, I would like to update the Principal's roles array to only have the roles that the user has been assigned for that asset type.

I am thinking I would do an authorization filter that takes care of looking up the roles the user has been assigned to based on the asset being viewed and loading them into the roles array. This way, the roles array will always reflect the permissions they have for the asset being viewed.

Then from the view, I can hide/show different parts of the page depending if they are in a specific group (User.isInRole)

Would this be the right approach to switching roles for the user depending on the asset type?

Comment: Is the asset something you can get from querystring?

Answer (score 0):

If these roles need to be applied across a request, and you can get the items identifier from header, query string, cookie, or session,  i would suggest possibly adding an httpmodule that would bind to the `AuthorizeRequest` event.  In that point you will want to provide your `IPrinciple` object with its custom implementation

the IsInRoles based on your rules.

Would this work, I'm mainly just guessing about your setup and on an ipad.